# Is there a version of “equine/equestrian”, or any other horse-related word, for a pegasus/pegasi?

Tags: terminology, writing, taxonomy, creative-writing

I’m a fantasy writer, and have encountered an issue. In regard to pegasi, I am unsure whether or not the words from the question title apply to pegasi, or if there are pegasus versions of those words.

So do they apply, and if not, what should the word or words be?

Comment: What are *pegusi*?

Comment: The plural of “pegasus.” But in hindsight, my spelling may be incorrect.

Comment: Oh. I read it as if someone thought to ***pay goosey** goosey gander* from the nursery rhyme, but then lost the *gander* bit. :)

Comment: Cheval/chevalier and also caballo/caballero, from the same Late Latin root plus PIE -ter/tor agentive.

Comment: Well, if we're using pegasus as a general descriptor rather than a proper name, it seems only fair to call the rider a bellerophon.

Comment: I have seen 'pegasi'. However, if I were being strict, I would say there was only ever one Pegasus; the word in that sense is a proper noun. I suppose you could call fictional winged equines pegasi if you wanted to.

Comment: In the case of calling a pegasus-rider a “bellerophon,” what might the adjective be? “Bellerophonic,” maybe “belleric” if shorter would be better. Possibly even “bellerian.” I’m open to better suggestions, of course.

Comment: @Bill We don’t do invented words here. But if you want to follow normal derivational morphology in English, then it would of course work exactly the same as the adjectival forms for *antiphon, antistrophon, colophon, harmoniphon, keraulophon, prosiphon, Typhon,* and *siphon* all work.

Comment: I see. I haven’t used this platform before, so please forgive my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *Pegasean*

Yes, there is! That word is the adjective *Pegasean*. The OED gives it the following sense:

> Of, relating to, or characteristic of Pegasus. Also: resembling Pegasus, esp. in his capacity for winged flight; (hence) poetically inspired or elevated.

It provides citations ranging between 1590 and 1988.

It notes that we most often now place the stress on the second syllable from the end, but that formerly we placed in on the third syllable from the end instead as attested by metrical evidence.

### Not *Pegasarian*, at least not lately

People also tried to use *Pegasarian*, but this didn’t catch on and is now marked obsolete:

> 1607   E. Topsell *Hist. Foure-footed Beastes* 323
>    The Pegasarian coursers of France, by the like change of horsses, run from Lyons to Rome in fiue or sixe daies.

### Use *pegasid* for seamoths

The noun and adjective *pegasid* relates to the [Pegasidae family of fishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasidae), also commonly called the seamoths.

One would speak for example of *pegasid biology* in this context.

### Not *pegasoid*, at least not any longer

Towards the end of the Nineteenth Century, there were a couple of isolated uses intended to mean either the mythological sense or the zoölogical sense, but these didn’t catch on, and so it too is now marked obsolete.

---

#### An astronomical note

The classical Latin nominative plural of *Pegasus* was of course *Pegasi*.

As in English where plural *dogs* and singular possessive *dog’s* both sound the same to our ear, in Latin’s second declension something similar occurred.

That’s why astronomers use *Pegasi* as a postpositive adjective in the possessive sense meaning “of Pegasus” to talk about stars in that constellation. The OED gives this recent example of that sort of thing:

> 1996   *New Scientist* 27 Jan. 17/1
>    They detected a wobble in the motion of the star 51 Pegasi, caused by an orbiting planet.

However, [Latin never used this word in the plural](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pegasus#Latin), because there was **only one creature named *Pegasus***. It was no more a generic for a whole set of creatures than *Medusa* was.

Comment: This is helpful, though only answers half the question. Of course, as a (self-identified) creative writer, that’s all I need.

Comment: "There was only one creature named Pegasus" IIRC didn't he have some children with Zeus's other horses, though?